# python3 / sqlite3 does not actually insert into DB?

Tags: python, sqlite

currently, I'm setting an SQLite database, using python.
I seem to lack something fundamental because rows are not actually inserted in the database on the disk.

I'm walking through a digital ocean tutorial from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-sqlite3-module-in-python-3

This is the code I'm attempting to run:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("aquarium.db")
print(connection.total_changes)
cursor = connection.cursor()
# cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE fish (name TEXT, species TEXT, tank_number INTEGER)")
print(connection.total_changes)
cursor = connection.cursor()
#cursor.execute("INSERT INTO fish VALUES ('Sammy', 'shark', 1)")
#cursor.execute("INSERT INTO fish VALUES ('Jamie', 'cuttlefish', 7)")
print(connection.total_changes)
rows = cursor.execute("SELECT name, species, tank_number FROM fish").fetchall()
print(rows)
connection.close()
```

Imagine running the code with all lines in the first execution.
I get the output:

```
0
0
2
[('Sammy', 'shark', 1), ('Jamie', 'cuttlefish', 7)]
```

I now have a file called aquarium.db and it has a correct schema, but the rows are never stored on disk.

Re-running the same code, omitting the lines I have commented out, I see that the file is indeed empty:

```
0
0
0
[]
```

What am I missing here?

BR,
Michael

Comment: Bad tutorial. You should be doing tutorials from the official Python sqlite3 docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to `commit()` see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit)

I slightly modified your code to be more clear

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("aquarium.db")
print(f"Number of changes {connection.total_changes}")
cursor = connection.cursor()

update = False
if update:
    try:
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE fish (name TEXT, species TEXT, tank_number INTEGER)")
        print(f"Number of changes {connection.total_changes}")
    except:
        print("Couldn't create table, it probably exists.")

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO fish VALUES ('Sammy', 'shark', 1)")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO fish VALUES ('Jamie', 'cuttlefish', 7)")
    # now you need to commit your inserts
    connection.commit()
    print(f"Number of changes {connection.total_changes}")
rows = cursor.execute("SELECT name, species, tank_number FROM fish").fetchall()
print(rows)
connection.close()
```